# Quandl data, API call

Tags: python, api, request, quandl

Recently I am reading some stock prices database in Quandl using API call to extract the data. But I am really confused by the example I have.

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/%s.json' % stock
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
raw_data = session.get(api_url)
```

Can anyone explain that to me?

1) for api_url, if I copy that webepage, it says 404 not found. So if I want to use other database, how do I prepare this api_usl? What does '% stock' mean?

2) here request looks like to be used to extract the data, what is the format of the raw_data? How do I know the column names? How do I extract the columns?

Comment: Can't comment on the quandl data format, but `% stock` is a string formatting operation (see details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)). Basically it is replacing the `%s` in the preceding string with the string referenced by `stock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

1. `% stock` is a string formatting operation, replacing `%s` in the preceding string with the value referenced by `stock`. Further details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)
2. `raw_data` actually references a Response object (part of the `requests` module - details found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response)

To expand on your code.

```
import requests
#Set the stock we are interested in, AAPL is Apple stock code
stock = 'AAPL'
#Your code
api_url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/%s.json' % stock
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
raw_data = session.get(api_url)

# Probably want to check that requests.Response is 200 - OK here 
# to make sure we got the content successfully.

# requests.Response has a function to return json file as python dict
aapl_stock = raw_data.json()
# We can then look at the keys to see what we have access to
aapl_stock.keys()
# column_names Seems to be describing the individual data points
aapl_stock['column_names']
# A big list of data, lets just look at the first ten points...
aapl_stock['data'][0:10]
```

**Edit to answer question in comment**

So the `aapl_stock[column_names]` shows `Date` and `Open` as the first and second values respectively. This means they correspond to positions `0` and `1` in each element of the data.

Therefore to access date use `aapl_stock['data'][0:10][0]` (*date value for first ten items*) and to access the value for open use `aapl_stock['data'][0:78][1]` (*open value for first 78 items*).

To get a list of every value in the dataset, where each element is a list with values for Date and Open you could add something like `aapl_date_open = aapl_stock['data'][:][0:1]`.

If you are new to python I seriously recommend looking at the list slice notation, a quick intro can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. I have one more question, if I want to read only the data of column 'Date' and 'Open', what command should I use? I tried aapl_stock['Date'][0:10], but it does not work.

Comment: So the aapl_stock[`column_names`] shows `Date` and `Open` as the first and second values respectively. This means they correspond to positions `0` and `1` in each element of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is highly appreciated.

Comment: One last question, how can I read the data year by year? Say from 1982-01-01 to 1982-12-31, this is year 1982, the same for year 1983, etc.

Comment: Looks like the quandl api supports a date range (at least version 3 does anyway). If you change the url by appending `?start_date=1982-01-01&end_date=1982-12-31` then the data you receive will be restricted to that range. Full reference [here](https://www.quandl.com/docs/api)